# Getting specific element from external site using jQuery / ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-domain

I am using jQuery and **[this plugin](https://github.com/padolsey/jquery.fn/tree/master/cross-domain-ajax)** to pull content from an external site.

It works great using the following code:

```
$.ajax({
       url: 'http://www.somesite.com/',
       type: 'GET',
       success: function(res) {
          $("#here").html(res.responseText);
       }
     });
```

But what I would really like to do, is only pull a section (div) from the target site, and I understand this is only possible when using the `load()` method, not `GET`.

I then found **[this code](http://blog.luutaa.com/jquery/how-to-get-specific-div-from-ajax-response/)** , but when I tried to build it into the code, it didn't seem to work, as such:

```
$.ajax({
       url: 'http://www.somesite.com/',
       type: 'GET',
       success: function(res) {
          $(res).find('div.content').each(function(){
              $('#here').append($(this).html());
         });

       }
     });
```

Looking into the request on Firebug, the request does seem successful, but the code can't seem to find the following tag: `<div class="content row">` on the target site.

Do I need to make sure the target element has an #ID, instead of a class?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your original success callback you're fetching your html contents from responseText, you should do the same in the second case:

```
   success: function(res) {
      $(res.responseText).find('div.content').each(function(){
          $('#here').append($(this).html());
     });
```

Using class="content" or id should work. However, you should be aware that the code above adds all *div*'s that have class content to your id="here" div, which might not be what you want. If you want just the contents of a specific element, use its *id* instead.

Comment: What about using find on an id? Would `find('div#content)` work?

Comment: @Gcap That will work (assuming there's a `<div id="content">` in html that is returned)

Answer (score 6):

Try using `jQuery.parseHTML();`

**Description:** Parses a string into an array of DOM nodes.

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'http://www.somesite.com/',
   type: 'GET',
   success: function(res) {
      var data = $.parseHTML(res);  //<----try with $.parseHTML().
      $(data).find('div.content').each(function(){
          $('#here').append($(this).html());
     });

   }
 });
```

because ajax response is a `string` and that way you can't use `.find()` method to find a dom node. so first you have to parse the string as dom nodes which you recieved from server then you can use `.find()` to select your target element.