# Add a part of page as a iframe

Tags: html, iframe

I want take a question of this site http://qstn.mthmtcs.ir  as a iframe to show in another site.
I don't want show all page. I want show just question  part.

```html
<iframe src="http://qstn.mthmtcs.ir/index.php?qa=80" width="100%" height="100%" align="center" ></iframe>
```

i want create a bbcode with this for my website.
people can insert url linke in post and show that question.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with an iFrame but you could use Ajax.

See the [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21430426/773263) for reference, and [this](http://blog.luutaa.com/javascript/jquery/how-to-get-specific-div-from-ajax-response/):

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://www.somesite.com/',
  type: 'GET',
  success: function(res) {
    $(res.responseText).find('div.content').each(function(){
      $('#here').append($(this).html());
    });
  }
});
```

You would then need to parse out the specific element you wanted to target.

Comment: who can exactly use this? i am elementary. show with example pls